# Asterisk Force Hangup On Inbound Calls

Tags: asterisk, dongle

I am new on Asterisk.
I have configured and installed Asterisk + FreePbx with 4 USB MODEM as FXO.
All is working fine, but I need block or hangup all inbound calls.
I possible make it from dondle.conf ? or where?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do do this you need to edit the context in the dongle.conf and then create a context in extensions.conf

The extensions.conf context can read

```
[dongle-inbound]
  s,1,Hangup()
```

That will simply hangup all calls that are passed to that context.